# React native connect to wearables

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, wear-os, wearables

everyone! I need help regarding the integration of React Native with wearables. Is it possible to create a React Native app that reads and connects to smartwatches/bands, displaying health-related data within the React Native app or sdk available to do?

Hello, everyone! I need help regarding the integration of React Native with wearables. Is it possible to create a React Native app that reads or connects to smartwatches or bands, displaying health-related data within the React Native app?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`react-native-wear`](https://react-native-wear.vercel.app), which is a fork of [`fabOnReact/react-native-wear-connectivity`](https://github.com/fabOnReact/react-native-wear-connectivity)